# In PostgreSQL, count how many observations match a list of criteria in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

Suppose I have a table, `cars`, which looks like this:

```
id  | model  | car_color
----+--------+--------
01  | Camry  | blue
02  | Elantra| red
03  | Sienna | blue
04  | Camry  | fuschia
05  | LX450  | pink
06  | Tundra | lime
```

Also suppose I have this other table, a non-exhaustive of colors, `colors`:

```
colors
-------
blue        
red 
fuschia
```

**In Postgres (or perhaps in any SQL variant), how can I count how many entries in `cars.car_color` match any of the entries in `colors.colors`?**

The answer here would be 4, as 'pink' and 'lime' don't appear in the `colors` table, but I can't get Postgres to spit this back for me. (In what I'm actually working on, the first table has dozens of millions of rows, and the second table I'm checking against has about 100k.) I'm trying things like this, to no avail:

```
select count(*) from cars
where "car_color" IN (colors.colors)
```

Here's the error:

`[42P01] ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "colors"`

My intuition is that this is something about my WHERE statement, but I can't figure out what. Nor can I seem to phrase this in such a way as to get good search results in Google or SX search -- I know I'm not the first (or the 257th) to ask this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close.  You need a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from cars c
where c.car_color IN (select co.color from colors co);
```

Postgres as a good optimizer, but sometimes `exists` works better:

```
select count(*)
from cars c
where exists (select 1 from colors co where co.color = c.car_color);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=93633642658acfa17227f157878575a8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Both suggestions run without error but return "0". Maybe it's because I don't follow the shortcuts/aliases you're using to refer to the tables, e.g. the "c." in "c.color" or the "co" "colors co". Can you clarify? (I'll edit the names of the columns in the original post to help.)

Comment: @logjammin . . . The `c` and `co` are just abbreviations for the table names.  However, if the queries are returning `0` then the values do not match in the two tables.

Comment: @logjammin . . . I added a db<>fiddle.  The code works.

Comment: Gordon, my man, what can I say? In the "real" dataset this example is a stand-in for, Postgres had dropped some leading zeroes in the `colors` table when I imported it from the original csv file. Your code does indeed work - and it told me nothing matched because nothing actually matched! I re-imported `colors` with a new data type for `colors.colors`, varchar(n), got the leading zeroes back in there, and got my answer. Salute, you utter king!  (PS: db<>fiddle is incredible and will come in very handy. Thanks for that, too.)